# Trouble Looping with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie at python and currently learning web scraping using `BeautifulSoup`. I am trying to get information on Steam to display the game name, price, and genre.  I can get my code to find all of this but when I put in in a for loop, it doesn't work. Can you identify the problem?

Thank you so much for the help!

**This will show everything I need(and more) on the page (name, price, genre)***

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Adventure/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=9)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for item in content.findAll("div", attrs={"id": "tab_content_NewReleases"}):
    print(item.text)
```

**This will only show the first game, therefore I believe it is not looping correctly***

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Adventure/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=9)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for item in content.findAll("div", attrs={"id": "tab_content_NewReleases"}):
    itemObject = {
        "name": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "tab_item_name"}).text,
        "price": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "discount_final_price"}).text,
        "genre": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "tab_item_top_tags"}).text
    }
    print(itemObject)
```

I'm expecting results like this but more than 1 results:

```
{
    'name': 'Little Misfortune', 
    'price': '$19.99', 
    'genre': 'Adventure, Indie, Casual, Singleplayer'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `content.findAll("div", attrs=.......` contains all of the results you want in the very first index (results[0]) so you only get the first result. When you iterate over it; you only search the html that contains the good stuff once, hence the one result issue. The solution is to then search the found html block which contains your desired results and split THAT into an iterable you can work with. Here is my solution:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Adventure/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=9)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
bulk = content.find("div", attrs={"id": "tab_content_NewReleases"})  # Isolate the block you want
results = bulk.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'tab_item'})  # Split it into the seperate results
for item in results:
    itemObject = {
        "name": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "tab_item_name"}).text,
        "price": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "discount_final_price"}).text,
        "genre": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "tab_item_top_tags"}).text
    }
    print(itemObject)
```

You got 90% of the way there, just missing that little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, Robert!! It makes total sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are working with the children so add in a child a for the selector. You could also make the parent the rows element i.e. #NewReleasesRows a

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Adventure/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=9)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for item in content.select('#NewReleasesRows a'):
    itemObject = {
        "name": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "tab_item_name"}).text,
        "price": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "discount_final_price"}).text,
        "genre": item.find("div", attrs={"class": "tab_item_top_tags"}).text
    }
    print(itemObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not selecting the right Tag. Use instead 'NewReleasesRows' to find the table containing rows of the new releases.
So code would be like this using CSS selector:

```
my_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(my_page_text, 'lxml')
print("mysoup type:", type(my_soup))

my_table_list = my_soup.select('#NewReleasesRows')
print('my_table_list size:', len(my_table_list))
```

Then you can look for the rows (after having checked that you got only one table (could use select_one too):

```
print(BeautifulSoup.prettify(my_table_list[0]))
my_table_rows = my_table_list[0].select('.tab_item')
```

and from there you can iterate

```
for my_row in my_table_rows:
    print(my_row.get_text(strip=True))
```

Result code:
R 130.00Little MisfortuneAdventure, Indie, Casual, Singleplayer
-33%R 150.00R 100.50TrailmakersBuilding, Sandbox, Multiplayer, LEGO
-10%R 105.00R 94.50Devil's Deck 恶魔秘境Early Access, RPG, Indie, Early Access
R 89.00Showdown BanditAction, Adventure, Indie, Horror
R 150.00HardlandAdventure, Indie, Open World, Singleplayer
R 120.00Aeon's EndCard Game, Strategy, Indie, Adventure
R 105.00Atomorf2Casual, Action, Indie, Adventure
-10%R 175.00R 157.50Daymare: 1998Indie, Action, Survival Horror, Horror
-25%R 79.00R 59.25Ling: A Road AloneAction, RPG, Indie, Gore
-10%R 105.00R 94.50NauticrawlIndie, Simulation, Atmospheric, Sci-fi
FreeOrpheus's DreamFree to Play, Adventure, Indie, Casual
-40%R 105.00R 63.00AVAEarly Access, Action, Early Access, Indie
-40%R 18.00R 10.80Angry GolfIndie, Casual, Sports, Adventure
-40%R 10.00R 6.00Death LiveIndie, Casual, Adventure, Anime
-30%R 130.00R 91.00Die YoungSurvival, Action, Open World, Gore

I hope that helps.
Best